# float to double (IEEE754) conversion

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, x86

I'm trying to convert 32bit `float` to 64bit `double` in asm on x86 architecture. The conversion is done by function written in asm and then I want to call it from C. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but memory pointed by `dst` seem to stay untouched and after `printf` program crashes. **I want to do it without any floating-point intructions.** Here's the code:

```
.686 
.model flat 
public _conv

.data
mantissa_mask dd 00000000011111111111111111111111b
exponent_mask dd 01111111100000000000000000000000b

.code 

_conv PROC
pusha
mov ebp, esp

mov esi, dword ptr [ebp+8] ; src
mov edi, dword ptr [ebp+12]; dst

mov dword ptr [edi], 0
mov dword ptr [edi+4], 0

mov eax, dword ptr [esi]
and eax, dword ptr mantissa_mask
mov dword ptr [edi], eax
xor edx, edx ; zero edx
mov ecx, 1
shl ecx, 29 ;ecx == 2^29
mul ecx ;so it's like `shl edx:eax, 29`
mov dword ptr [edi], eax
mov dword ptr [edi+4], edx

mov eax, dword ptr [esi]
and eax, dword ptr exponent_mask
shr eax, 23 ;put exponent on lowest bits
sub eax, 127 ;exponent in float is coded enlarged by 127
add eax, 1023 ;in double it's enlarged by 1023
shl eax, 20 ;exponent in double starts on 20bit of 2nd byte
or dword ptr [edi], eax

;sign bit:
bt dword ptr [esi], 31
jc set_sign_bit
    btr dword ptr [edi+4], 31
    jmp endthis
set_sign_bit:
    bts dword ptr [edi+4], 31
endthis:

popa
ret
_conv ENDP

END
```

And the C code:

```
void conv(float * src, double * dst);

int main()
{
    float src = 4.5f;
    double dst = 0.;
    conv(&src, &dst);
    printf("%f\n", dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not accidentally compiling as 64 bit. Also, set `dst` to non-zero so you can check that indeed it's not touched. And, as always, use a debugger.

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: @Jester I had some bugs which I found just now. Sorry for that, I edited code in the question.

Comment: Conversion is not handling sub-normals correctly.  Recommend to create `conv(float * src, double * dst);` as C code first to insure proper functionality - then write it is .asm.

Comment: Technically, SSE2 is not a "coprocessor", so you could use `cvtss2sd` without violating your restriction.  But I think you actually meant you wanted to do it using only integer instructions, i.e. software floating point.

Comment: shr eax, 23
sub eax, 127
add eax, 1023
shl eax, 20 can be done in 2 instructions. It's a detail but it is counter-productive to write assembly if you cannot do it in two instructions, because if you had written the same four operations in a high-level language, the compiler would have known to transform what you had written into these two instructions. And it would be more readable. And it would more easily work.

Comment: Ok, it finally worked. Posted answer with final code.

Comment: @PascalCuoq yes, but it'd less readable. I wanted to know what's happening in the code

Comment: @Criss: That's what comments are for.  Or if you want to write it out step-by-step in code you could single-step in debug mode, do it in C.

Comment: And BTW, you can write self-documenting asm like `shr eax, 23-20` / `add eax, -127 + 1023`.  (And if necessary, `AND` to mask off the low bits you didn't get rid of with 2 shifts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally it works. Very helpful was Jester's advice about args access. Stupid thing, but hard to notice. Here's final code:

```
.686 
.model flat 
public _conv

.data
mantissa_mask dd 00000000011111111111111111111111b
exponent_mask dd 01111111100000000000000000000000b

.code 

_conv PROC
pusha
mov ebp, esp

;+36 and +40 since pusha
mov esi, dword ptr [ebp+36]; src
mov edi, dword ptr [ebp+40]; dst

mov dword ptr [edi], 0
mov dword ptr [edi+4], 0

;mentissa:
mov eax, dword ptr [esi]
and eax, dword ptr mantissa_mask
mov dword ptr [edi], eax
xor edx, edx ; zero edx
mov ecx, 1
shl ecx, 29 ;ecx == 2^29
mul ecx ;so it's like `shl edx:eax, 29`
mov dword ptr [edi], eax
mov dword ptr [edi+4], edx

;exponent:
mov eax, dword ptr [esi]
and eax, dword ptr exponent_mask
shr eax, 23 ;put exponent on lowest bits
sub eax, 127 ;exponent in float is coded enlarged by 127
add eax, 1023 ;in double it's enlarged by 1023
shl eax, 20 ;exponent in double starts on 20bit of 2nd byte
or dword ptr [edi+4], eax

;sign bit:
bt dword ptr [esi], 31
jc set_sign_bit
    btr dword ptr [edi+4], 31
    jmp endthis
set_sign_bit:
    bts dword ptr [edi+4], 31
endthis:

popa
ret
_conv ENDP

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Your primary problem is accessing the arguments. Since you did `pusha` the arguments are **not** at `[ebp+8]` and `[ebp+12]`, rather at `[ebp+36]` and `[ebp+40]`. A debugger would have shown you this right away. Even with those changes your code is still broken though.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that about `pusha`. Completely didn't notice that. With some bug fixing (i've done an edit of the code in question) and changing args accessing it doesn't crash, but output 0. Please look at the code once again since there was an edit.